# Getting Input tag id, value in webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium

Html

```
<table id="tblRenewalList" class="adminlist dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;" aria-describedby="tblRenewalList_info">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="odd">
<td class="alignCenter">
<input id="chkRenewal_868" class="chkPatent" type="checkbox" onclick="RenewalSelection(this)" companyid="33" value="868">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with above Html i want to scrape the `id, value`

following are my java code, when i try with below code, its return empty values, please find the code

```
WebElement inputValues = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='tblRenewalList']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"));
            String idValue = inputValues.getAttribute("id");
            String ed2 = inputValues.getAttribute("value");
```

following are my expected output

id = chkRenewal_868
value = 868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document isn't well-formed, i don't know if that matters for webdriver, 
but XPath must be

```
//*[@id='tblRenewalList']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input
```

Comment: Thanks will changed the X Path, getting my expected